Next.js app randomly breaks with no changes
The following code for my next.js was working perfectly. Then when I npm run dev this morning without changing a single line of code all the componenets are all over the place the middle compnenets where there is the image asnd text on the left and then 2 videos with text scroll by on the right doese not work at all. The  component no longer shows up on the screen at all and some of the css got messed up. Is there any reason why this would happen ???? Code below.
'use client';

import '@coinbase/onchainkit/styles.css';
import OnchainProviders from './OnchainProviders';
import SwapComponents from './SwapComponents';
import './globals.css';
import Image from 'next/image';
import logo from './logo.png';
import datapics from './stats.png';
import GreenDot from './GreenDot';
import PriceUpdater from './PriceUp';
import Data1 from './stats';
import Data2 from './statsTw';
import Data3 from './chart';
import GifLikeVideo from './gifVid';
import coin from './coin.png'
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {WalletComponents} from './WalletComponents';



const App = () => {
  const [showInception, setShowInception] = useState(false);
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(false);
  const summaryRef = useRef(null);
  const rightContentRef = useRef(null);
  const headerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (summaryRef.current && rightContentRef.current) {
        const summaryRect = summaryRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const rightContentRect = rightContentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        const scrollProgress = (windowHeight - summaryRect.top) / (rightContentRect.height - windowHeight);
        setShowInception(scrollProgress > 0.4);
      }

      if (headerRef.current) {
        const headerRect = headerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        const originalPosition = 150;
        setIsSticky(window.scrollY > originalPosition);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <OnchainProviders>
      <WalletComponents />
      <div className={`font-mono flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen relative`}>
        <div 
          ref={headerRef}
          className={`flex items-center transition-all duration-300 ${
            isSticky 
              ? 'fixed top-4 left-4 z-50 transform scale-90' 
              : 'relative mt-[150px]'
          }`}
        >
          <div style={{ marginRight: '1rem', transform: 'translateX(9px)'}}>
            <GreenDot />
          </div>
          <div style={{ marginRight: '0.5rem' }}>
            <Image
              src={pic.src}
              alt="Frame"
              width={40}
              height={40}
            />
          </div>
          <PriceScript />
        </div>
        
        {isSticky && <div style={{ height: '150px' }} />}
        
        <SwapComs />

        <div className="w-full flex justify-center relative">
          <div className="sticky top-0 left-0 w-1/2 h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center" ref={summaryRef}>
            <Image
              src={logo.src}
              alt="Stats"
              width={260}
              height={260}
            />
            <p className="font-mono text-xl mt-8"> 
              Slogan here
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="w-1/2 flex flex-col items-center" ref={rightContentRef}>
            <div className="h-[90vh] w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
              <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-[-10vh]">
                <GifLikeVideo 
                  src="/Vid.mp4"
                  width={440}
                  height={160}
                />
                <p>
                  <span style={{ fontWeight: 500,fontSize: '1.2rem' ,textShadow: '0 0 0.5px currentColor'}} className="text-2xl">Title</span> This is where text one will go.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className={`h-[90vh] w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center transition-opacity duration-500 ${showInception ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'}`}>
              <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-[-30vh]">
                <GifLikeVideo 
                  src="/Vid2.mp4"
                  width={400}
                  height={120}
                />
                <p>
                  <span style={{ fontWeight: 500 ,fontSize: '1.2rem',textShadow: '0 0 0.5px currentColor'}} className="text-2xl">Title2</span> This is where text two will go.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center mt-0">
          <Image
            src={datapics.src}
            alt="Stats"
            width={400}
            height={400}
          />
          <div className="flex flex-row justify-center space-x-4 mt-6">
            <div className="relative" style={{ top: '-30px', left: '-120px' }}>
              <Data1 />
            </div>
            <div className="relative" style={{ top: '-15px', left: '-20px' }}>
              <Data2 />
            </div>
            <div className="relative" style={{ top: '-270px', right: '-120px' }}>
              <Data3 
                curveControlX={60} 
                curveControlY={120} 
                dotPositionX={50} 
                dotPositionY={25} 
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </OnchainProviders>
  );
};

export default App;

I tried comand Z a few times to see mabey I had accidentally deleted a section or something but that was not the case at all.

Please share the Error occured in terminal and Browser for easy debugging.

there are no errors in the console @KannuMandora and the code did not change...It worked perfectly yesterday now it is all over the place and some components are showing up some fonts are not rendering its a disaster. But I did not change a single thing.

For ease, could you be able to share a minimal repo code in codesandbox? because it's hard to debug at this stage.
